# Sorting an IEnumerable <T> present inside IQueryable<User>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, sorting, sql-order-by

I have an object where it returns IQueryable  which contains below code snippets:

```
public string employeeId{get;set:}
public string employeeName {get;set:}
public IEnumerable<Role> userRoles {get;set:}
```

And under the model "Role" I have 2 properties below:

```
public string roleDescription {get;set:}
public string roleNumber {get;set:}
```

The problem here is I am able to do sorting based on employeeId and employeeName but not based on the roleDescription and roleNumber since the type is of IEnumerable.

Comment: And when is one `userRoles` greater than another `userRoles`?

Comment: @Servy. Never. In this case we can assume the role number will be the same for all but the role description varies from user, admin, writer,etc.

Comment: You'd have to be doing a `SelectMany` to order the `Role` properties.  Can you show us your actual query.

Comment: If you have no way of defining which is "greater than" another, then you can't sort on it.

Comment: @juharr. I had tried both Select and SelectMany but it didn't.

Comment: It's going to be hard to help you if you don't show what you tried, some example data and what you expect to get.

Comment: @Servy. Why can't I sort based on the role description which differs for all the items?

Comment: @user3715379 `userRoles` doesn't have *one* description to sort on.  It has an unknown number of descriptions.  You need to define how to determine whether one *collection* is greater than, equal to, or less than, another *collection*.

Comment: @user3715379 do you mean sort by **first** role description?

Comment: @Aleksey. Yes exactly!

Comment: @servy Each IEnumerable item will contain only one item and I have to sort based on the role description.

Comment: I can only assume that you aren't permitted to update the design, otherwise it's rather silly to use an IEnumerable to store a SINGLE value.  Better to just use the custom type "Role" as an individual entity.

Now, if it's possible for users to have multiple roles, that's different, and you will need to declare a comparer for "Roles"

Comment: @Nevyn. That's right. Even I thought the same that why the old developer has put in IEnumerable for an single item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on *Each IEnumerable item will contain only one item* - it will be something like:

```
Employees.OrderBy(e => e.userRoles.First().roleDescription)
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me give it a try here.